# My pihole "works" but blocks nothing, what is wrong?

Tags: dns, raspberry-pi3, ads, pihole

I just installed everything on my new raspberry pi and I wanted to test pihole. I installed it, and he is now running, I have the gui working too. My problem is when I set the dns on my phone/other computer on the ip adress of the pi, it seems that it uses the second dns while pihole remains the main dns.

I tested on my computer with nslookup windows command line and it seems to work(it even recognised the name pihole), but when I use then Web sites like canyoublockit.com, nothing seems to work.
I used Chrome browser on Android and Windows (both failed) but my pihole Still recognised the ip adresses of them(in clients), and it even says that they 16 queries for 495.
I did not modify anything about pihole itself. What's wrong?

Comment: This is off-topic here (not a programming question). Probably best to ask on [raspberrypi.se]